# How to fix the header and scroll content

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am beginner to CSS and I know it is very easy:

Issue:
I have below html sample page and when I scroll the page, header is not getting fixed at one place. What I am missing here ? Please  help;

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="myHeader">
  <h2>TEST</h2>
</div>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div class="" style="margin-top:2%;position:relative">
    <div class="">
      <span class="sectionHeader">Section A</span>
      <p style="margin-top: 24% !important;margin-bottom: -22% !important;margin-left: 2%;position:relative;">Section B</p>

      ome text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
      his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
      laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae
      gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque
      et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.
      <div>
        <p style="margin-top:45%;margin-bottom:-43% !important;margin-left:2%;">
          Section C
        </p>
        ome text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
        his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
        laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae
        gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset
        concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae
        voluptatibus.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello, add some code to help others understand your question

Comment: I have tried to paste the code and sof was throwing error "Please add some context to explain the code sections" so created jsfiddle  . Please help

Comment: why downvote?? it doesn't motivate

Comment: Class .sticky is not available in the CSS

Comment: .sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}

Comment: @Gerard http://jsfiddle.net/guc9hfdz/1/

Comment: @Rockyrealstart .sticky + .content { padding-top: 102px; } does not make sense, because there is no element with the .content class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide something for the css class ".sticky" in your CSS part. How about something like `position: fixed;`

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  myFunction()
};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sticky { 
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" id="myHeader">
  <h2>TEST</h2>
</div>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div class="" style="margin-top:2%;position:relative">
    <div class="">
      <span class="sectionHeader">Section A</span>
      <p style="margin-top: 24% !important;margin-bottom: -22% !important;margin-left: 2%;position:relative;">Section B</p>

      ome text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
      his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
      laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae
      gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque
      et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.
      <div>
        <p style="margin-top:45%;margin-bottom:-43% !important;margin-left:2%;">
          Section C
        </p>
        ome text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur
        his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert
        laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae
        gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset
        concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus. Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae
        voluptatibus.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh man , I have sticky class but no z- index
 .sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;

} after adding z-index it worked . Thank you so much

Comment: But I didn't get the usage/imp of z-index here(May be it's silly question)

Comment: @Rockyrealstart z-index is only one approach here. you can also set ´position: fixed;´ to your .header directly. But than you have to margin your form from top with the headers height. you can try leaving the z-index out, than you see that the text is overlapping the header.

Comment: Thanks got it. The text was overlapping the header

Answer (score 0):

try adding this code to your html and css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  position: fixed;
    width: -webkit-fill-available;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    top: 0;   
}
.form{
   padding-top:10%;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" class="form" runat="server"  >
```

Comment: After adding z-index it worked . Thanks for your help